# Erro ao tentar somar campo hora(varchar) sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma query que retorna os seguintes dados:

```
SELECT * FROM METAS

   mes  lj  saldo   meta
    4   2   153:59  123:00:00                                         
    4   2   25:33   00:00:00
    4   2   29:57   08:00                                             
    4   2   38:58   45:00:00                                          
    4   2   94:47   20:00                                             
    4   2   23:41   15:00:00                                          
    4   2   215:37  70:00:00                                          
    4   2   213:41  120:00:00                                         
    4   2   235:38  80:00:00                                          
    4   2   36:13   13:00:00
```

Mais preciso que ela seja feito dessa forma:

```
SELECT 
  mes,
  lj,
  SUM(saldo) as salto_total,
  SUM(meta) as meta_total
   FROM METAS
```

Ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Mensagem 8117, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1 Operand data type varchar
>   is invalid for sum operator.

O motivo é que meus campos saldo e meta são do formato varchar.

Já me indicarão essa  [dica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979664/cast-varchar-to-time-and-sum-in-sql-generates-error)

Mais ela retorna o seguinte erro:

> Mensagem 245, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1 Conversion failed when
>   converting the varchar value '00:00' to data type int.

Como poderia efetuar esse calculo ?

Comment: quando a meta é `08:00`, o correto seria `00:08:00` né (HH:mm:ss) ?! você tem um sério problema pra guardar esses dados. Um simples campo numérico ou inteiro resolveria o problema

Comment: e o saldo... `213:41` seria `213:41:00` já que no meio não tem 3 casas decimais (HH:mm) ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Os resultados esperados são : meta:1068:04:00 Saldo: 494:00:00

Comment: olha a trabalheira que é pra normalizar esses dados como @JoseDiz postou... eu pensaria em refazer essas colunas logo...

Comment: Para acumulação de horas que ultrapassem 24h a sugestão é o uso de coluna do tipo numérico, usando minutos como unidade. Desta forma, qualquer cálculo é simples e converter para hhh:mm também é simples.

Comment: Entendo e concordo com vocês , mais esses dados que vem de uma outra empesa onde eu não posso manipular a estrutura do banco de dados, posso consultar, mais não posso alterar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eis sugestão inicial, considerando-se as informações fornecidas até o momento:

```
-- código #1 v3
declare @Mes int;
set @Mes= 4;

with 
normalizaHMS as (
SELECT lj, 
       case len(saldo) - len(replace(saldo, ':', '')) 
            when 1 then saldo + ':00'
            when 2 then saldo end as saldo,
       case len(meta) - len(replace(meta, ':', '')) 
            when 1 then meta + ':00'
            when 2 then meta end as meta
  from METAS
  where mes = @Mes
),
separaCampos as (
SELECT lj, saldo, meta,
       cast(parsename(replace(saldo, ':', '.'), 3) as int) as saldoH,
       cast(parsename(replace(saldo, ':', '.'), 2) as int) as saldoM,
       cast(parsename(replace(meta, ':', '.'), 3) as int) as metaH,
       cast(parsename(replace(meta, ':', '.'), 2) as int) as metaM
  from normalizaHMS
),
somaCampos as (
SELECT lj, 
       sum(saldoH) as sum_saldoH,
       sum(saldoM) as sum_saldoM,
       sum(metaH) as sum_metaH,
       sum(metaM) as sum_metaM
  from separaCampos
  group by lj
),
agregaCampos as (
SELECT lj, 
       (sum_saldoH + (sum_saldoM / 60)) as sum_saldoH,
       (sum_saldoM % 60) as sum_saldoM,
       (sum_metaH + (sum_metaM / 60)) as sum_metaH,
       (sum_metaM % 60) as sum_metaM
  from somaCampos
)
SELECT @Mes as mes, lj, 
       cast(sum_saldoH as varchar) + ':' + right('00' + cast(sum_saldoM as varchar), 2) as saldo,
       cast(sum_metaH as varchar) + ':' + right('00' + cast(sum_metaM as varchar), 2) as meta
  from agregaCampos;
```

Comment: Perfeito,Obrigado.